# Picking elements from priorityqueue that fit criteria

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I have an instance of `PriorityQueue<SomePlayerObject>`. It has been constructed with a `Comparator` which imposes an ordering that is inconsistent with equals: it orders `SomePlayerObject` based on the time the player has been online.

`SomePlayerObject` has a method: `boolean isValid()`.

I want to `poll()` from the `PriorityQueue` the first element (according to the custom comparator) that fits the criteria that `isValid` returns true.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you could really sanely do here is just keep calling the normal `poll()` method until it `isValid()`.  That's almost certainly the way you *should* do it.

You could conceivably call `queue.removeIf(e -> !e.isValid())` in Java 8, but that's not going to be any more efficient than the previous approach.

Comment: But `poll()` removes elements from the queue, and the state of `isValid()` can change. Perhaps `PriorityQueue` is not the best solution? The element needs to stay in the queue to potentially be accessed later.

Comment: Apparently not.  I suppose you could re-insert the invalid elements after you've found a valid one, but that's the best you'll be able to do really.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for other ideas then.